# Default value for an embedded field in Hibernate. java.sql.SQLException: Field 'url' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, hibernate, embeddable

I have an abstract class `A`, class `B` and `C` are subclasses of `A`. Class `B` has an embedded field `d`. Now when I try to save an instance of `B` everything is fine. However on creating an instance of `C`and saving it, I get an error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'string' doesn't have a default value.
```

Eg classes:

```
public abstract class  A {

}

@Embeddable
public class D {

    private String string;
}

public class B extends A{

    @Embedded
    @NotNull
    private D d;
}

public class C extends A {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got is `java.sql.Exception` telling you that:

```
`Field 'string' doesn't have a default value.`
```

From the wording I assume you are using MySQL, and what the error means is, that your `string` field was not populated at insertion time and declared as not null. You would receive the exact same error if you were to insert a record into that table and leave the `string` column empty.

What is causing your problem in the end is that you have the same table used for both classes, the `string` column added for the sake of object `b` and not populated in case of using `c`.